# c/c++ analogue to c# System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManager

Tags: c#, c++, c, buffer

Is there a c/c++ analogue or something similar to c# BufferManager class?

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not provide a solution for this. But there are some open source implementations  of a buffer pool. For instance [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3526/Buffer-Pool-Object-Pool) or [this one.](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/src/titaniumc/BufferPool.h)

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cop6726sp07/assign/assign1.htm)

> The LRU buffer manager will be C++ class that will implement the
>   following, fairly simple header (you should put this header verbatim
>   into the file LRU.h). Please note that while you do have to implement
>   a C++ class for this assignment, I am not asking you to use any of the
>   flashier C++ functionality (such as templates, inheritance, and so
>   on), though of course you are free to use these constructs within your
>   code. Thus, it should be very easy for a C programmer to adjust and
>   complete the assignment.